# undefined method `map' for "MD":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm struggling to create a dynamic dropdown box arrangement.  Thanks to StackExchange Ruby community, I was able to create the first dropdown box.  What I'd like to do, is have the user select a group of banks in a particular state, but keep getting the following error message from my f.grouped_collection_select form: undefined method `map' for "MD":String.  I looked at [ActionView::Helpers::Forms](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jO5SpYctA-s), but nothing seems to work.  Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.  I think I also have to add jquery code too?  Here is my current view code:

```
 <%= form_for @boli do |f| %>

 <%= f.label :state %>
 <%= f.collection_select :state, (Boli.order(:state).select("DISTINCT ON (state) id, state")), :id, :state, include_blank: true %>
 <div>
   <%= f.label :bank %>
   <%= f.grouped_collection_select :bank, Boli.order(:bank), :state, :name, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
</div>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: for the grouped select do you want to have the banks grouped under state headings or the states grouped under bank headings?

Comment: Banks grouped under the state heading

Comment: Do you have a model `State`?

Comment: no.  The model is boli.  State and bank are two boli attributes.

Comment: If I thought hard enough I could provide an answer, but I don't want to because it would go against the grain of my being. You need to have a separate model for each _thing_ in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group banks by state. This implies that there is either a one-to-many (one state to many banks) or a many-to-many relationship between them.

The one-to-many relationship implies `Bank` is a model that either has `state` as an attribute or references another model `State`.

The many-to-many relationship implies that both `Bank` and `State` are models joined by another table.

With both `bank` and `state` as attributes of another model it's unfeasible to model the relationship between them.

In order to use `grouped_collection_select` you should have both as models.

Comment: thanks for your feedback.  I was finally able to create some code that is capable of making dynamic changes to various attributes in one model as opposed to making two different models.  Will certainly heed your advice moving forward.  Thank you.